# Is HTML5 Datalist element supported in FirefoxOS?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, firefox-os

Is HTML5 data-list supported in Firefox OS?
I can see in [this MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist) article that it is supported in Firefox 4.0 and gecko 2.0 for desktop. And I can see for Mobile too it has the exact same settings. But I cannot get this to work in Firefox OS simulator 1.3 (stable).

So is it supported or I am doing something stupidly wrong (very much possible).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this is a [bug in FirefoxOS](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=869846). Try using a polyfill.

Comment: Yeah I can see a 2012 "new" [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=808308) (duplicate of the one you showed). *sigh*

Comment: See [Relevant Dropdowns: Polyfill for Datalist](http://css-tricks.com/relevant-dropdowns-polyfill-for-datalist/).